# Axiomatic characterization of the integer numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, integers

Peano axioms characterize natural numbers, they use neither sums nor multiplication. Is there an axiomatic characterization for the integer numbers which uses neither sums nor multiplications? I mean, is there a non-algebraic characterization of the integer numbers?

Best regards.

Comment: Hello. Can you elaborate a bit on "they use neither sums nor multiplication"? The usual Peano axioms include axioms like "$n + 0 = n$" and "$n \cdot 0 = 0$", which do seem to involve addition and multiplication, so I'm not sure exactly what you're asking. $\Bbb Z$ can certainly be characterised by axioms to the effect of "$\Bbb Z$ is an ordered ring whose nonnegative part satisfies (second-order) PA", for example, or by modifying the induction-related parts of PA to go "in both directions".

Comment: @Izaak Presumably OP is using axioms employing an injective (1-to-1) successor operation $S$. To extend this to $\Bbb Z$ we want $S$ to be invertible, so we also have a predecessor operation $P = S^{-1}.\ \ $

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen, Peano axioms can be stated without sums, and therefore without multiplication. They can be stated using the notion of "successor"

Comment: This is not true. The peano axioms include axioms for addition AND multiplication. If we remove the multiplication axioms , we arrive at the Presburger arithmetics , but this arithmetic is NOT equivalent to PA. In fact , it is too weak to even describe the property of a natural number being a prime number although multiplication of natural numbers can be reduced to repeated addition.